How to return value with matching week day to all future week ranges

Column B are dates, beginning from B2 e.g 29 Jul 2024
Column C are amounts, being from C2 e.g. $100.00
Row 1 are date week ranges beginning from D1 e.g. 29 Jul 2024 - 04 Aug 2024

What I'm trying to do is auto populate the future week range, with amount from C2, in which B2 day 'dd' would fall for all matching week ranges on row 2.
For instance, I would expect to see amount $100.00, with date 29 Jul 2024, auto populate in week ranges 26 Aug 2024 - 01 Sep 2024, 23 Sep 2024 - 29 Sep 2024, 28 Oct - 03 Nov 2024 etc
I tried a few array formulae but not fully working. Also tried using variations of IF statements  by splitting beginning and end dates of ranges into separate rows but I think text vs date is throwing things off.
Below is when range beginning and end are split to rows 2 and 3
ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(DAY($B$4)>=DAY(D2),DAY($B$4)<=DAY(D3)),$C$4,"")

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
